# Melhor método para carregar imagens

Tags: css, wordpress, amp

Eu tenho uma página AMP que eu carrego a imagem do logotipo inserindo o link dentro da tag img, assim:

```
<amp-img src="//i2.wp.com/www.meusite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/lgootipo.png" alt="logotipo" width="356" height="137">
```

Porém, qual seria a melhor prática para carregar essa imagem ?

Eu pensei em chamar a imagem com o `background-image: url("...")` dentro da tag `style`

Será melhor deixar do jeito q está ou carregar com a imagem com CSS ??

Comment: Se a sua preocupação é Performance x Qualidade sua resposta está aqui: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O HTML deve conter informações que são semanticamente relevantes para o seu site, e o CSS deve oferecer informações que são estilísticas (decorativas).

Vários tipos de leitores irão ignorar completamente o CSS, e você não quer que ignorem a logo. Em outras palavras, a logo possui relevância semântica para o site, e é por isso que possui o atributo "alt", caso o leitor não possa ver a imagem (aproveito para sugerir que você melhore sua "alt", descrevendo a aparência da logo).

A regra é: se eu tirar a informação, o site deixará de fazer sentido, ou fará menos sentido? Se sim, a informação deve ficar no HTML, se não o ideal seria colocá-la no CSS.